# LDAP Active Directory Domain Computers

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have an active directory domain that houses all our user accounts and also all our computers and devices on connected to our domain. I have used LDAP and adLDAP libraries and functions in PHP mostly for authentication but there is a new project I am working on and it would require a slightly different means of using those libraries. The new site I am working on is an asset or inventory management site. I plan to still use LDAP authentication but I would also like to simplify the process of inventorying computers in the building by allowing you to sync them over for active directory. Can this be done? I know about searching but is there a way to query an entire OU and increment through each item and grab information about those items.

I would like to query our computer OU and pull out information like the office number, computer name and basic information like that. I know how to search for a specific user but I am not really looking for a member here but rather computers, is it similar? I can provide code I have used for searching for users if need be. I have tired looking for people doing similar things but all the tutorials and questions I see generally deal with searching for users and authentication or differences between bind and search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is an acronym for Lightweight Directory Access Protocol.  What that really means is that it is a driver to a database.  The underlying premise of Active Directory is built on top of a simple relational database structure.

This means you can access any data element about an entity (I.E. office number, computer name, etc...).  The only limitation here is going to be what your LDAP user authenticating to the Directory has the "Permission" to view.  If someone from Accounting logs into your application, and you application browses the Directory as that user (Standard/Default Setup) keep in mind that user may not be able to see all elements in the Directory.

This also means that as long as you structure your query to the database correctly you can access any element you have permission to.  Since you are already familiar with using LDAP authentication, the DN, OU, structure must be familiar.  The syntax is continued, but the items names change based on which properties you wish to access. I would recommend querying the directory with a highly privileged user and spitting the output to `print_r()` to learn the structure, and walk the database. Although if you have someone intimately familiar with the structure of the Directory, they may be able to provide you the proper pathing, and using a combination of these functions should get you everything you need to know:

```
ldap_get_attributes()
ldap_get_entries()
ldap_get_option()
ldap_get_values()
```

Hope this helps!  If you would like me to clarify anything or explain further just let me know in the comments and I'm happy to update my answer!